# Django Rest Framework: Get unique list of values from nested structure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to return a list of strings from a deeply nested structure of data.  In this scenario, I have a API that manages a chain of bookstores with many locations in different regions.

Currently, I have an API endpoint that takes a region's ID and returns a nested JSON structure of details about the region, the individual bookstores, and the books that can be found in each store.

```
{
  "region": [
    {
      "store": [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Baz"
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "store": [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Bar"
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "store": [
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Baz"
          }
        },
        {
          "book": {
            "name": "Qux"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My models look like the following.  I am aware these models don't make the most sense for this contrived example, but it does reflect my real world code:

```
class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=512)


class Bookstore(TimeStampedModel):
    value = models.CharField(default="", max_length=1024)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Region(TimeStampedModel):
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Bookstore)


class BookstoreChain(TimeStampedModel):
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
```

The serializers I created for the above response look like:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "__all__"


class BookstoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Bookstore
        fields = "__all__"


class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = BookstoreSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = "__all__"


class BookstoreChainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = RegionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BookstoreChain
        fields = "__all__"
```

I'm not sure what my view or serializer for this solution need to look like.  I'm more familiar with writing raw SQL or using an ORM/Linq to get a set of results.

While the above response is certainty useful, what I really want is an API endpoint to return a unique list of book names that can be found in a given region (`Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, `Qux`).  I would hope my response to look like:

```
{
    "books": [
        "Foo",
        "Bar",
        "Baz",
        "Qux"
    ]
}
```

My feeble attempt so far has a `urls.py` with the following `path`:

`path("api/regions/<int:pk>/uniqueBooks/", views.UniqueBooksForRegionView.as_view(), name="uniqueBooksForRegion")`

My `views.py` looks like:

```
class UniqueBooksForRegionView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Regions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ???
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the output you would like to get? also adding your models might help too.

Comment: @NavidZarepak, I edited my question above to include the request information.  Hopefully this is enough to get some insight about what I'm not understanding to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want that response as a part of `BookstoreSerializer` response on a field named `books`?

Comment: I'm not particular about how the response looks exactly, I just need a list of the book names in an easy to iterate structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you start from **region** you have to get the stores, so you can filter the books in the stores, here is a solution which will work.

## Note:

Avoid using `.get()` in `*APIView` because it will trigger an error if the request does not have the ID, you can use `get_object_or_404()`, but then you cannot log your error in Sentry.

To get an element from an `*APIView`, use `filter()`.

```
import logging as L
class UniqueBooksForRegionView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs)
       regions = Region.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field])
       if regions.exists():
          region = regions.first()
          stores_qs = region.stores.all()
          books_qs = Book.objects.filter(store__in=stores_qs).distinct()
          # use your book serializer
          serializer = BookSerializer(books_qs, many=True)
          return Response(serializer.data, HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
          L.error(f'Region with id {self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]} not found.')
          return Response({'detail':f'Region with id {self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]} not found.'}, HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

## Note

Here is the flow, the code may need some tweaks, but I hope it helps you understand the flow

Comment: I am having some issues with this line: `stores_qs = Region.objects.filter(pk=filter(uid=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field])).stores.set()`.  I get the error `filter() takes no keyword arguments`.  Is the `pk=filter(...)` supposed to be using Python's filter function or Django's filter function?

Comment: @roundtheworld sry man my bad Region.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]).stores.set() it was a typo

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.  Two followup questions: 1. I get an error on the `stores_qs` line that says: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'stores'` 2. Doesn't `set()` take a parameter?

Comment: @roundtheworld sry again mb i dint verify the code wrote it pretty quickly Region.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]).stores_set.all() will return the desired data

Comment: I think there is still an issue here because `filter` returns a `QuerySet` and not a model.  I get the error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'stores_set'`

Comment: yeah... should use .get instead of filter, filter returns queryset

Comment: Okay, I think I got it working now, but I had to make one more change...I removed `_set` from `stores_set` because it gave me the error `object has no attribute 'stores_set'`.  I don't understand what the `_set` is trying to accomplish.

Comment: _set should get the set of the related objects when it is many to many it hits the manyToMany table check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ search for _set

Comment: Hmm, adding `_set` causes the error `'Region' object has no attribute 'stores_set'`...but if I remove `_set` from you example, the code works like I hoped it would.

Comment: Glad to hear that! you can accept my answer then :)